# Why Uploaded File Size always show null for a telerik upload?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, file-upload, razor, telerik

I use Telerik control to upload files.

```
@(Html.Telerik().Upload().Name("attachments").Multiple(true)
.ShowFileList(false).Multiple(true).ClientEvents(events => events.OnSuccess("onSuccesfulFileUpload")                                                    .OnUpload("validateUpload")).Async(async => async.Save("Save", "Home").Remove("Remove", "Home")
.AutoUpload(true)))
```

javascript:

```
function validateUpload(e)
{
alert(e.files[0].size);
}
```

But the size is coming as null. I read that File size is not available in all browsers.

Pls provide some help.

Answer (score 0):

> I read that File size is not available in all browsers.

Yes, you read correctly. This is available only to browsers that support the HTML5 File API. For example this will not work in Internet Explorer 9 or earlier.

Comment: I get filesize in Controller and hence I can validate. The thing is I have to show a popup through javascript that "File exceeds its max size". Save method in controller can return action result as `Content("MaxSizeError")`. I was unable to collect this returned content as no javascript is present in between. If i add OnError("onUploadError") event also it cannot differentiate between errors. Any help.